# Converting a timestamp in milliseconds in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a timestamp in milliseconds:

```
1420066991000
```

That [translates](http://currentmillis.com/) into UTC:

```
Wed Dec 31 2014 23:03:11
```

and local time:

```
Thu Jan 01 2015 00:03:11
```

However if I try to convert it into a timestamp in Postgres, using to_timestamp, it gives me a wrong datetime:

```
select to_timestamp(1420066991000);
46970-02-17 13:03:20+00
```

Since to_timestamp, [expects a double precision input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html), I also did this:

```
select to_timestamp(1420066991000.0);
46970-02-17 13:03:20+00
```

but the results are the same.

Am I missing something in my Postgres configuration, like some timezone setting? or is it a bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`to_timestamp()` converts unix time, that is time in seconds. Since you have data in miliseconds you should divide it by 1000.

```
select to_timestamp(1420066991000/1000);
```

Comment: Dividing by `1000.0` will allow you to preserve millisecond-level accuracy, if desired.

Comment: Oh, the facepalm I'm feeling right now. Thank you for this correct & helpful answer!